# Python triplet of numbers

Tags: python, math

I would like to write a program for Pythagorean Triplet. Program for numbers `a`, `b`, `c` return Pythagorean three natural numbers `a1`, `b1`, `c1` such that `a1 >= a`, `b1 >= b`, `c1 >= c`.

```py
def Triplet(a, b, c):
    a1 = a
    b1 = b
    n = 5
    m = 0
    while True:
        m += 1
        while b1 <= (b + n * m):
            a1 = a
            while a1 <= b1:
                #while c1 > c:
                    c1 = (a1 * a1 + b1 * b1) ** .5
                    if c1 % 1 == 0:
                        return a1, b1, int(c1)
                    a1 += 1
            b1 += 1

print(Triplet(3,4,6))
```

For input: `(3, 4, 6)`, output should be: `(6, 8, 10)`. Where is the error?

Comment: What output does it give now? What did you find out when stepping through the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you've commented out your incorrect check for `c1 > c`, but not replaced it with anything.

If you just add that condition back before the return, it works:

```
def Triplet(a,b,c):
    a1=a
    b1=b
    n=5
    m=0
    while True:
        m+=1
        while b1<=(b+n*m):
            a1=a
            while a1<=b1:
                c1=(a1*a1+b1*b1)**.5
                if c1>=c and c1%1==0:
                    return a1,b1,int(c1)
                a1+=1
            b1+=1


print(Triplet(3,4,6))
```

Comment: small correction, It should be c1>=c . other wise (3, 4,5) input will give (6,8,10), instead of (3,4,5)

Answer (score 1):

If you change  the condition to `if c1%1==0 and c1>=c:` then the issue will get fixed.

I ran it locally and i got (6, 8, 10)